# Nivo Slider jQuery plugin in WordPress doesn't rotate images. How do I fix that?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming, nivo-slider

I am adding the nivo slider jQuery plugin to a WordPress theme but I can't get the images to rotate. They all load but they don't rotate. Here is the section of my header that applies to the slider:

```
    <?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery('#slider').nivoSlider();
});
</script>
```

And here is the div where the images are being displayed:

```
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
    <?php
    $slides = $data['pingu_slider']; //get the slides array

    foreach ($slides as $slide) {
        echo '<h1 class="image_title">' .$slide['title'].'</h1>';
        echo '<img src="'.$slide['url'].'" alt="test">';
        echo '<p class="nivo-caption">' .$slide['description'].'</p>';
    }

    ?>
</div>
```

The site where the slider is located is at http://sandbox.nspirelab.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your page, you're loading jQuery twice.... version 1.4 right after version 1.4.2.

But one major issue is that you're calling `jQuery` in your `head` but jQuery does not even exist yet until down in the `body`.  You need to include jQuery before you include the plugins or call the code.

Only include jQuery **once**, then include your plugin, and then call your function.  This can be done in either the `head` or the `body`.

```
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        jQuery('#slider').data('nivoSlider').start();
    });
</script>
```

And finally, since we're talking about a Wordpress theme, take a look at using `enqueue` to prevent the loading of jQuery multiple times.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: Ok thanks. It's a starter theme and I am not sure why it's calling jquery twice...or where it's calling jquery for that matter. Obviously I am new at all of this.

Comment: @user715564, you can use the console tools in your browser to see that jQuery is being called twice (by a Wordpress plugin, it seems).  Use the `enqueue` script which is intended to prevent this.  Then move your Nivo code so that it comes **after** the jQuery include.